# Cannot import google-cloud storage package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I try to import GCP storage package.

```
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
from google.cloud import storage
```

error code:

```
----> from google.cloud import storage
--->  from google.resumable_media.requests import RawDownload
ImportError: cannot import name 'RawDownload' from 'google.resumable_media.requests' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/__init__.py)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: have you set up your ```GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS``` ? If not follow the steps in this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication

Comment: What's the version of the package? Can you please run

pip show google.resumable_media.requests

Comment: What is the version of *google-resumable-media** installed?

Comment: It seems that one of the packages in the google cloud storage failed to install yesterday. I contacted Google and they solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please can you share root cause and solution / workaround in order to add valuable content to community. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pit In fact, I don’t know how this bug came about. When I open new Python notebook in colab workspace and only type Two-line code. ` !pip install google-cloud-storage > log.txt   from google.cloud import storage`   everything is working fine. But sometime when I try to install GCP storage package among the code that I already have something written this error will happen and it’s no use re-executing it several times. This problem continues occasionally.

Comment: hello, looking for a while I found [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/9891) github issue that could help you understand what is going on, also you can check your version of cloud-volume is 0.65.4 or higher in your requirements.txt